# Page formatting when using images

Tags: lyx, page-breaking, miktex, sections-paragraphs

New Lyx user, not very good in page formatting. whenever i insert an image, the whole page formatting get messed up. like in the below figure. In my code the above paragraph was after the pic. but in the output the paragraph has gone above the picture.

[image]

And start of every page has so much gap. I want this if the start of the page has new section.

In the below pic, you can see the picture has taken the whole page. That's because the start of the page has so much gap. i could easily fit in couple of paragrah below the picture.

[image]

How do I magange this properly, except for this i am loving Lyx.

Comment: Welcome, to avoid the gaps and keep the pictures where you want them, the pictures need to be cut in halves, putting one part at the bottom of the page and the other part at the top of the next. All gaps avoided.

Comment: And because the above method is silly, LaTeX moves the pictures to the next page and fills the space with text that would have been below the graphic. It is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Johannes_B,Thanks for your suggestion, but how do i do that? any example

Comment: In my point of view this is totally unrelated to  LyX! This happens everytime float is used

Comment: in the float positioning mark "top, bottom, here if possible" and remove "here definitely". This will make the float... floating

Comment: This sounds nasty, but it is intended to be nice: Let Latex decide it, and live with it. It is good, really. Ever tried to put pictures in Word, and got mad every time they moved around into the margins when you did a small text edit? Spent hours to repair, and had to redo that again after the next change. Forget it. Write your document, and Latex puts the pictures for you. Again and again, so you don't have to worry about it. Perhaps use \FloatBarrier from the {placeins} package to prevent a floating floating beyond a certain point. But then sometimes you have to accept even larger spaces.